# Wear OS foreground service pauses after a few minutes

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, bluetooth, wear-os

I'm building a Wear OS app using Flutter (I don't believe this is a flutter-related issue).

My app needs to read data from a BLE device every 2 seconds.
I'm trying to run the long-lasting task of reading every 2 seconds in a foreground service.

When the app is backgrounded, it pauses at a certain time.
For example, if the task runs for 10 minutes in the background (all along I can see the foreground notification) the data it collects in the local database seems to pause after a few minutes, then continue when the app comes to the foreground again.

How can I solve this issue? I want the app to run in the background until the user stops it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use GATT notifications instead?

Comment: @Emil I think this is an Android-related issue, how will using GATT help me in this?

Comment: Notifications are sent automatically by the GATT server when a characteristic is updated. Those are preferred over GATT reads if you want to just receive continuous updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to retrieve sensor data from a foreground service. After a while, I stopped receiving sensor updates.

It's possible that the device enters a power-saving mode, also known as the DOZE mode.
You can try to keep the CPU awake by using a wake lock.
More information on wake locks in Android can be found here: https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/scheduling/wakelock#cpu

The equivalent in Flutter should be something like this: https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock